# Angular 9: how to restart an animation if trigged again before the animation end

Tags: angular

I have a very long (time-wise) animation

```js
    highlightAnimation: trigger('highlight', [
        transition('* <=> *', [
            style( {backgroundColor:'orange'}),
            animate('10s ease'),
        ])
    ])
```

And I would like it to restart if it is trigged again before the end of the animation. How can I do this?